# What does /.*=/ mean in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does /.*=/ mean in the following jquery?

```
var id=this.href.replace(/.*=/,'');
this.id='delete_link_'+id;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a regular expression that will select all characters before and including an equal sign.

The '.' means any character other than a newline.

The '*' means the character before it can appear any number of times.

The '=' is the regular equals sign.

So any character ('.') any number of times ('*') followed by an equals sign ('=').

Comment: '.' means any character different to \n, which includes '='
Also, * is greedy, so this regex will search for the last =

Answer (score 4):

That's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). 
The code will replace everything before the '='-sign (and the equal sign) with an empty string. So it will delete the = and everything before it.

My guess is that your url looks something like this http://mysite.com?id=3 then your variable id will contain 3.

Comment: And, since the * is greedy by default, it will erase everything up to the rightmost =.

Answer (score 0):

The /.*=/ is a regular expression. It replaces any number of characters followed by an equals sign with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) (or regex).

A regex is a search and replace method which uses pattern matching to locate parts of a string that fit a pattern. (Similar to how a wildcard `dir *.*` lists all the files in the current directory).